# Read column headers in CSV using fileHelpers library

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I have a CSV file where the headers indicate in which order the information is going to appear in the detail lines. An example would be:

```
COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3
VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3
```

but could also be

```
COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN1
VALUE2,VALUE3,VALUE1
```

The class would look like this

```
public class CSVImportLineItem
{
    public string Column1 {get; set;}
    public string Column2 {get; set;}
    public string Column3 {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way (using [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/)) to read the headers in and then determine the mapping to the properties based on the header order?

Comment: Mapping to what properties?

Comment: The properties would be the same name as the column headers but the order they appear in would be variable.

Comment: Yes but where? In a class I take it? We don't have scope of where these properties are from your question :)

Comment: The properties are in a class.

Comment: So what is your class structure? Post the **FULL** code instead of refering to just `Properties` assuming that we know what you know.

Comment: Did the edit make it a little clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you have to specifically use the `FileHelpers` library?

```
  //Use File.ReadAllLines();
  List<string> lines = new List<string>() { "Column1, Column2, Column3", "1,2,3" };
  var cols = lines.First().Split(',');
  List<CSVImportLineItem> imported = new List<CSVImportLineItem>();
  var v = lines.Skip(1).ToList().Select(line =>
     {
       CSVImportLineItem item = new CSVImportLineItem();
       var values = line.Split(',');
       for (int i = 0; i < cols.Count(); i++)
       {
         item.GetType().GetProperty(cols[i].Trim()).SetValue(item, values[i], null);
       }
       return item;
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Filehelpers has the level of robustness I need, it's just missing the ability to work with variable headers.

Comment: @WilliamHurst For this section in particular though, any reason you can't do the above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the one of the [ClassBuilder helper classes](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/runtime_classes.html).

```
DelimitedClassBuilder cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("LineItem");
// First field
cb.AddField("Column2", typeof(string));
// Second field
cb.AddField("Column1", typeof(string));
// Third field
cb.AddField("Column3", typeof(string));

engine = new FileHelperEngine(cb.CreateRecordClass());
LineItem[] lineItems = engine.ReadFile("FileIn.txt") as LineItem[];
```

You can change the order of the fields based on the contents of the first line (which you can read outside of FileHelpers).

See also, [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833322/1077279).