# FileHelper ReadFile() returns null

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm working with the great FileHelpers library (version 2.9.9). However I've been stuck for some hours now and I'm not able to work this issue out. I would like to load my file into an array of my CustomerClass object. I would like to change the order of the fields dynamically utilizing the DelimitedClassBuilder. I found an answer here on Stackoverflow which shows how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833322/767926. I'm not able to do it even following that answer. However it works fine if I just use the class directly with the FileHelperEngine instead of DelimitedClassBuilder. Could somebody please help me out here?

This is the object i would like to create an array of from the csv file:

```
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
public class CustomerClass
{
    public string CustomerId;

    public string FirstName;

    public string LastName;
}
```

This is the code I'm using to create the array:

```
public void ReadFile()
{
    DelimitedClassBuilder cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("CustomerClass", ";");
    cb.AddField("CustomerId", typeof(string));
    cb.AddField("FirstName", typeof(string));
    cb.AddField("LastName", typeof(string));

    FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(cb.CreateRecordClass());
    engine.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.IgnoreAndContinue;

    string filename = @"C:\temp\customerfile.csv";

    DataTable dt = engine.ReadFileAsDT(filename); // Works fine
    object[] test = engine.ReadFile(filename) as object[]; // Works fine

    CustomerClass[] customers = engine.ReadFile(filename) as CustomerClass[]; // Returns null (probably because the 'cast' is invalid, see line below)
    customers = (CustomerClass[])engine.ReadFile(filename); // Throws InvalidCastException (Unable to cast object of type 'CustomerClass[]' to type 'MyNamespace.CustomerClass[]'.)
}
```

This is the file contents:

> CustomerId;FirstName;LastName
>
> 1;James;Brown
>
> 2;Robert;Miller
>
> 3;David;Green

Comment: Is there more than one `CustomerClass` in your project, in different namespaces?

Comment: What is the result if you use `var customers = engine.ReadFile(filename);`. What type does `customers` resolve to?

Comment: And what are the types inside of the array? They will obviously be `object`, but what type is stored in them?

Comment: The type didnt resolve to object it resolved to CustomerClass (but a different CustomerClass than my CustomerClass since this one is constructed dynamically with the DelimitedClassBuilder). It contains 4 objects. The object names are CustomerId, FirstName and LastName.

Answer (score 0):

Try the fully qualified class name:

`DelimitedClassBuilder cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("MyNamespace.CustomerClass", ";");`

Comment: I've tried that. That throws an exception: "The string 'MyNamespace.CustomerClass' not is a valid .NET identifier". I've also tried to use cb.NameSpace = "MyNamespace.CustomerClass", this throws an InvalidCastException as well...

Comment: Is CustomerClass in the same project?  If not, you need to specify the assembly also.

Comment: CustomerClass is within the same project.

Comment: I don't know then.  I tried looking up source for the library, but it's blocked here at work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments you have provided I'd suggest using the following:

```
var customers = engine.ReadFile(filename)
                      .Cast<*type of the class coming back from ReadFile*>()
                      .Select(c => new MyNamespace.CustomerClass()
                                       {
                                            CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
                                            FirstName = c.FirstName,
                                            LastName = c.LastName
                                       })
                      .ToArray();
```

You will need to provide the type of the class returned from `engine.ReadFile` to the call to `Cast`. The call to `Select` will then create an instance of your `CustomerClass` for each customer returned.

Comment: This throws an invalidcast as well: Unable to cast object of type 'CustomerClass' to type 'MyNamespace.CustomerClass'. As for the void this is just a simple example i constructed, the method looks quite different. I just wanted to make sure this small simple example worked...

Comment: Just to be clear, `CustomerClass` is coming out of the call to `ReadFile` and `MyNamespace.CustomerClass` is what you want?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I tried to add the correct namespace to the cb.NameSpace property but that gives an invalid cast as well.

Comment: Thanks for the provided solution, I know there are workarounds for my problem, I was looking for a solution utilizing the FileHelpers library since when googling around there seems to be other people that have managed to set up such a solution...

Comment: Thank you for your new suggestion! I tried it, but this generates an invalidcastexception as well unfortunately. For the moment I'm accessing the data with reflection in my array object.